# Animate Extending a Curve

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

How can I animate a curve extending? I'd like the animation to look like a circle extruding along the path.

I've found lots of tutorials like [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves/Editing/Advanced), using the taper/bevel objects in the curve settings, but I'm trying to do to it without the funky taper off the front of the extrusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using a Bézier extrusion with animated start/end values, which was added in Blender 2.65. You'll need two curve objects: the path and the circle (if you don't have a circle curve, just add a **Curve** → **Bezier Circle**).

First, select the path, and set its **Bezier Object** (under the curve options tab) to the circle. This will take care of the extrusion portion. To avoid the "funky taper," just don't set the taper object.

Then, animate the **End Bevel Factor** value. To do this, go to frame 1, and set the End Bevel Factor value to 0. Hover over it and press <kbd>I</kbd>, or <kbd>RMB</kbd> → **Insert Keyframe** to insert a keyframe. Then, go to the frame where you want the transition to end, set the factor to 1, and insert a keyframe again.

This image demonstrates the two key things to set:

[image: Example image]

*NB* Using the circle as a curve object allows you to have a more flexible swept object. If all you need really is a circle with no endcaps, just set the **Bevel Depth** to a higher value than zero and set the **Fill** to *Full* instead of *Half*.

Comment: Ahhh so simple. I've been trying unsuccessfully to understand the taper object... still don't get it at all, so thought I was missing something there.

Comment: The taper object adjusts the thickness along the length of the path. If you don't want this, don't use it.

Comment: If you want to animate the bevel of a closed path (cyclic), you won't be able to. You can, however, "break" a cyclic path and place a point exactly where the loop would "close", that way it'll look like it's a cyclic path but it won't be and you will be able to use the method mentioned above to animate it! :)