# I'm trying to create a fuse simulation

Tags: particles

I am trying to simulate a fuse burning up to a bomb then do an explosion with the bomb. But I can get only so far with the fuse. I am having brain freeze when it comes to getting the sparks off the fuse end to show along with the object used to simulate the fuse before burning to go away after it has been "burned".

I am thinking of using a curve type to have the fuse follow it (but have not implemented that yet. nor do I know if I really need to yet, I haven't gotten that far yet.)

I have the sparks set up and working but the object pieces being used to simulate the fuse are too big when the particle system explodes them.

Wondering how do I decrease the size of the object particles?

file included to give you a better idea of what I am talking about that I am in this post.

oh I had a baked cache on that particle system file so you might want to look at that before running it.

[image]

I've gotten this far so far, still trying to work out an longated object to look like a fuse then have it looking like it is actually burning away as the fuse sparks move down towards the bomb.

the cure does not allow keyframes on its x,y,z dimensions so I can srink it as it goes along the path . having given it a shape, or using the curve modifier.

Comment: So is the core of the question how to resize particles or how to get the fuse to move along a curve?

Comment: I get the partial sized, I get them to move along the length of the object, the curve follow path I may not have to use to get this to work.  it is to make that same object that is eing used as the fuse look like it is actaully a fuse being burnt off as it goes along, the object parts are too big, if I deselect view emmiter then it does not show the object that is suppose to be the fuse. only the sparks that are omming off it going down its length.

Comment: @RayMairlot I've tried setting an ojects x,y,z, size animation to srink in size frame 1 it is at a large set size. frame 50 zero out x,y,z. but when I go back to frame 1 the x,y,z dimentions do not fully reset. some stay at zero. only z seems to go back. if I do just x it srinks from center and not one end to the other

Comment: Check my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71900/modeling-a-sparkling-flare It could be a little help.

Comment: This [answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/building-animation/49891#49891) may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

One technique for eroding the fuse would be to keyframe the Bevel Factor of a bezier curve.

The reverse of [Animate Extending a Curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/animate-extending-a-curve) .

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen a tutorial for this a long time ago but I cant find it now.
It split the problem in two:

creating the particles:

Use an empty or a small object, that moves along the curve, to emit the particles.

burning the fuse:

animate the texture coordinates of the fuse. the texture would be the glowing part of the fuse on one side and transparant on the other to create the ilusion the fuse is gone.

EDIT:
Here's a crude example of how it can be done:

To anomate texture uv coordinates you need to enable the AnimAll plugin. (in the user preferences screen, under addons)
You will allso need a black and white image to use as texture (added at the botom of the post).
next unwrap the fuse so all the UVs are in the white like in this image.
[image]

then in the Animation tab under AnimAll check UVs and insert a key frame (see the top left part of the screen-shot below)
Next, set the time to the frame on which the animation should end. And move the UVs to the black part of the image. Then add another keyframe.
[image]

Create a node set-up like in the screen-shot below, replacing the dark red Difuse BDSF for your own fuse material. 
[image]
now the fuse should disappear nicely in animation. (because of the plug-in the UVs in the UVeditor don’t always update, to view the animation with alt-a switch to object mode first)

There are definitly other methods that work. There are a bunch of detailed  burning paper tutorials around which is a similar problem. You could try googleing those.

Happy blending.

[image]

Comment: This answer could use alot more details, maybe picture and steps?

Comment: I've gotten to not showing the emmiter for the sparks, using another like object then keyframe off x from lengtht to zero setting the rgian to 3d cursor , the cursor being placed at the end do that it no longer srinks in the middle, that way it srinks along the length with the way I have the sparks particles set up to follow x then getting to a bomb that also has the explotion set to it then having that one go off at the same frame that the particles for the sparks end. it look crude right now, this one is really crude looking. just trying to get the procedures down.

Comment: Shrinking the object will be very hard if it is not a straight cylinder because the part that has not burned will distort. The solution with the half transparant texture will avoid that distortion, it will simply hide the burnt part.

Comment: To make the fuse disappear at a constant rate, you may also want to change the interpolation mode to linear. (in the curve editor select the uv-keyframes and under "key" - "interpolation mode" - "linear")