# 'Modeling' a sparkling flare?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, light, smoke-simulation

[image]

[image]

I want to recreate the above images for an animation. How do I go about it? I tried using particle systems and smoke simulators but to no avail.
Also, I want to model a sparkler, but more akin to a sparkling point or sphere that emits in all directions.

Comment: Check this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCMyvcc3ZaU

Comment: @LukeD yes, I'm familiar with that tutorial, but i ended up making my 'model' into amalgam of satanic lines, I tried every possible combination for the particle system which  **I** could think of

Comment: Particle system is fairly simple to set (high normal emiter and 0 gravity) but I'm struggling with those sparks 'outside'. They are changing directions realy quick. I've managed to set particle system inside ico sphere as collision but when I try to animate this ico sphere to get random bounces particles doesn't respond to it.

Comment: Check this out: http://imgur.com/a/R9zHU

Comment: @LukeD that's perfect, just need the center to be a sphere and a bit bigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Final (almost) result**

[image: final]

I will not go trough all steps in detail as they aren't part of the question (animation, modeling this sparkling stick and such).

### Particle system

Create *IcoSphere* and scale it to be a bit wider then stick and add to it *Particle System*.

Create another one and move it to another layer - you will use it as particle object.

[image: Particles]

Most important settings are:

1. **Lifetime**, short lifetime does not allow particles to bounce and long one will get all of them messy.
2. **Emitter Geometry > Normal**. This will give our particles initial speed.

The rest of them are just some little tweaks.

**Do not forget to set *Gravity 0* in *Field Weights* tab.**

### Collision system

This is the tricky devil.

1. Create *IcoSphere* (Subdivisions 2) go to *Edit Mode* and *Wireframe view* (<kbd>Z</kbd>).
2. Select all - <kbd>A</kbd> and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then *Edge Split*.
3. Select all again and set *Pivot Center* to *Individual Origins* then scale it down little bit. You should get something like this:

[image: 2]

4. Now you can duplicate it and make them smaller, bigger, with any rotation - as you like. Remember to set *Pivot Center* back again to *Median Point*.
5. Final step, still in *Edit Mode* add another *IcoSphere* and make it the biggest one. This will be boundry for our collision system.

My final setup looks like this:

[image: 3]

> Creating collision system is the worst part, everything depends on it,
>   so you must try to make it right. If you want sparkles to be bigger,
>   make whole thing bigger, if you want them to be more round - scale
>   down less after edge split, to have smaller holes between faces.

Go back to *Object Mode* and in *Physics tab* add *Collision*. Set *Particles* > *Permeability* to *0.3*. This will allow particles to "break" collision system. You can set it to 0, then nothing (yup, almost) go trough.

Hide this object in *Outliner* and set it to not renderable. Eye and camera Icon.

### Materials

We will need only two materials, for sparks (particles) and particle emitter. Select *IcoSphere* you've moved to another layer and add this node setup:

[image: 4]

Select *IcoSphere* which is emitter for particles and add to it *Transparent* node with pure white color.

### Motion Blur

Go to *Render* tab, check *Motion Blur* and set it to 1.10.

And that's it.

**Here is .blend file with all animations:**

[image]

Comment: So, there's one icosphere that's an emitter, another icosphere that's the particle and a third one that's a collision object. and the third icosphere has an edge split icosphere inside a regular icosphere, correct? So, is the emitter smaller than the third icoshphere?

Comment: Yes, emitter should be as big as the stick (little wider) and in third IcoSphere you can duplicate as much as you like them. In my blend file there are 4 if i recall it correctly.

Comment: ok, consider if i have to use this thing for a laser or welding animation, how would i add a trailing effect to it? like you know, after a laser has burn over an area the burn part is red hot before cooling off

Comment: Dynamic Paint. You can even make cut hole with it. There is plenty question and answers about it around here.