# Sparkler-Like Sparks?

Tags: particles

I'm looking to make a spark burst. But I want it more stylized than just a simple burst of particles... Does Blender 2.82 have the capabilities to make a "sparkler" type spark? References show that they almost have another spark emitting from the original spark... Image below.
[image]

Comment: Please check this similar request: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71900/modeling-a-sparkling-flare